# Where is the right OS X 10.9 source using "kloglevel"

Tags: macos, finder, smb, debug

MacOS X 10.9 and 10.9.1 contain a Finder bug which is revealed upon using
SMB v2 servers. (This bug is signaled to Apple, and shortly described here:
[smb v2 Finder bug / Mavericks](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24657220#24657220)).

I found with `man nsmb.conf` that a kernel debugging level is possible:

```
 Possible keywords may include:

 Keyword       Section    Default    Comment
               A B C      Values
 [...]
 kloglevel     + - -      0          Turn on smb kernel logging
```

But this is useless if I don't even know if this is a bitpattern
or an integer.

Searching within the [Kernel source tree](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-109/), I'd like to find where this
debugging level is used and how.

How is it possible to locate the source (.c or .h file) which is
defining or using this debugging level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessary sources are located here:

[Apple MacOS X 10.9 open source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-109/) within:

```
smb-697-1.1
```

Once downloaded, this tarball must be expanded with:

```
gzcat smb-697.1.1.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

Within this source tree the relevant sources may be identified with:

```
cd smb-697.1.1
find . -type f -exec grep -H -i loglevel {} \;
```

And finally we find that:

```
kernel/smbfs/smbfs_vfsops.c
```

initializes:

```
smbfs_loglevel =  args->KernelLogLevel;
```

and that:

```
kernel/netsmb/smb_subr.h
```

defines:

```
#define SMB_NO_LOG_LEVEL                0x00
#define SMB_LOW_LOG_LEVEL               0x01
#define SMB_ACL_LOG_LEVEL               0x02
#define SMB_IO_LOG_LEVEL                0x04
#define SMB_AUTH_LOG_LEVEL              0x08
```

and uses:

```
if (smbfs_loglevel & SMB_AUTH_LOG_LEVEL) \
```

Hence `kloglevel` is a bit pattern on 4 bits.